# Auth token in REST API

Tags: api, security, rest

If I have a client that passes an encrypted auth token (a token which includes an authorization key, the user id, and a created timestamp) to my REST API, if I am just decrypting this auth token on the server side and ensuring that the token is still valid (i.e. hasn't expired), is this enough? Or should I also be validating this auth token against a list of currently valid auth tokens for this user?

I guess I am asking because, if I have to verify this token by doing a database lookup for every API call, then won't this be too much overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Can your token be invalid even though the expiry date has not passed? If yes, then indeed you would need to check against a list.

Ofcourse there will be overhead, but it all depends on whether during peak times you can handle the load (easily). If not, you can always offload it these keys to in memory storage, e.g. memcached, redis etc.